# Thread execution issue

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, execution

I'm approaching C programming with threads and I can't get this program to work properly. Basically there's a vector with k elements, n threads and each thread has to calculate the max on its k/n elements.

My code is (please note it's not the whole code):

```
// Struct code used later
struct maxStruct 
{
    double *vettore;
    int dimensione;
};

// Gathering data input from user 

[ . . . ]
vector = (double *) malloc (dimensione * sizeof(double));
pid_thread = (int *) malloc (numero_thread * sizeof(int));
thread = (pthread_t *) malloc (numero_thread * sizeof(pthread_t));

// Generating the vector

[ . . . ]
for (i = 0; i < numero_thread; i++)
    {
        e = generaStruct(i, vettore, dimensione, numero_thread);
        if (status = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, calcolaMassimo, (void *) e))
                {
                    pthread_perror("pthread_join", status);
                    exit(1);
                }
    }

//Note that the function doesn't calculate the max, I've coded it in this way
//in order to see whether it was being called by each thread and apparently it is not.
void *calcolaMassimo(void * e)
{
    printf("Sono chiamata!!\n");
    struct maxStruct *sottoVettore = e;

    printf("Dimensione: %d\n", ((*sottoVettore).dimensione));

}
```

Apparently this function is not being called by each thread and I can't figure out why. Will you please help me solve this issue?

Comment: How do you know the function is not being called by each thread?  Printf is not thread safe; unless you synchronize access to it you won't get the results you expect.

Comment: @antlersoft: In Linux`s libc `printf` is, in fact, thread-safe.

Comment: What are you doing after creating the threads?

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt I think it should execute the code of the calcolaMassimo, where the maximum of each subvector is calculated by each thread, then I would invoke a pthread_join in order to get the maximum found by each thread...

Comment: Maybe you can reduce your actual code to something that reproduces the problem but is small enough to post? As it stands it looks like the problem is probably in a detail that's not in the code you posted. You might also want to add the platform details, particularly if you're doing this on Windows.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: you can find all my code here --> http://pastebin.com/JD9AL74a and I'm compiling on Linux/Ubuntu.

Comment: @Haunted86: Well, it looks like the problem is exactly what Abhay Buch said in his answer - you need to join on the created threads to wait for them to complete before exiting, or you need to exit from `main()` by calling `pthread_exit()` instead of `exit()` in `main()` so that the process stays alive until all your threads are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a minor nit pick, the idiomatic way to write `(*sottoVettore).dimensione)` is `sottoVettore->dimensione`.

The process containing all of threads will exit when `main()` exits. I know you said you're joining in you're actual code so that should not be an issue but if you're not joining in the test code then that could be an issue.

It is also possible that the issue is not that the code in each thread isn't executing, but that the statements aren't actually reaching `stdout`. You might want to try a `fflush(stdout)` at the end of `calcolaMassimo` and see if that changes things.